# Как изменить шаблон в коде modx revo

Tags: modx, revo

У меня есть шаблон 1 и 2. По умолчанию отображается 1, а мне надо если передан определенный параметр - изменить его на 2. Где и что мне надо прописать?

Пробовал разные варианты из гугла - не работают или я не туда вставляю

Answer (score 0):

Для отображения той же самой страницы, но с другим шаблоно в modx существуют Symlink(Символическая ссылка) - https://docs.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/structuring-your-site/resources/symlink/using-resource-symlinks

Comment: у меня задача стоит, что бы сменить шаблон через код. извините, если я не верно задал вопрос

Comment: Внимательно прочитай что я написал. Всё сделали в коде до тебя, чтобы ты мог одним переключателем сделать как тебе нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте, тут можно сделать так:
1) Добавить нужный "параметр" через TV и менять его в ресурсе, меняя таким образом отображение шаблона
введите сюда код
2) Использовать фильтры ввода-вывода в шаблоне, отлавливая нужные параметры через сниппет. Подробнее о фильтрах смотрите тут - https://docs.modx.pro/system/the-basics/filters-input-and-output